# Project Euler 11: Largest product in a grid, Python3

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, python-3.x

> [Project Euler #11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)
>
> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same
>   direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

I've seen some of the solutions of the problem and although they are in Python3, my solution has some differences.

Pylint rates it 7.27/10 and I will add docstring eventually. Some of the lines are too long(104/100) and `fl` is not a good name for a file and I agree.

The main issues are comparing `product` and `product_temp` and calculating the sum for a diagonal from down left to upper right is inconsistent with the calculating the other products.

The code:

```
#!/bin/env python3

"""
https://projecteuler.net/problem=11

In a 20x20 matrix iterate over all the rows, columns,
diagonals(left up -> down right, down left -> upper right)
and find the largest product of 4 numbers in the same direction

"""

def list_ints():
    with open('./textfiles/grid2020.txt') as fl:
        array = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in fl]
    return array

def biggest_product():
    grid = list_ints()
    product = 0
    product_temp = 0

    col = 20
    row = 20
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            #for row
            if i + 3 < 20:
                product_temp = grid[i][j] * grid[i + 1][j] * grid[i + 2][j] * grid[i + 3][j]

                if product < product_temp:
                    product = product_temp

            #for column
            if j + 3 < 20:
                product_temp = grid[i][j] * grid[i][j + 1] * grid[i][j + 2] * grid[i][j + 3]

                if product < product_temp:
                    product = product_temp

            #for diagonal from upper left to down right
            if i + 3 < 20 and j + 3 < 20:
                product_temp = grid[i][j] * grid[i + 1][j + 1] * grid[i + 2][j + 2] * grid[i + 3][j + 3]

                if product < product_temp:
                    product = product_temp

    #another loop from the other diagonal
    #diagonal left to upeer right
    for i in range(20, -1, -1):
        for j in range(20):
            if i + 3 < 20 and j - 3 >= 0:
                product_temp = grid[i][j] * grid[i + 1][j - 1] * grid[i + 2][j - 2] * grid[i + 3][j - 3]

                if product < product_temp:
                    product = product_temp
    return product


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(biggest_product())
```

**Edit:**  Now I see the comments for calculating row and col comments are reversed.

Comment: There was a bug in the initial code I've posted, but thanks to ChatterOne I've managed to fix it. Please give the improved version a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the potential improvements would be to extract the logic of generating the 4 numbers in each of the directions (let's even generalize it for `k` numbers). What if we would create a *generator* that would do this for an arbitrary square matrix and `k` input numbers:

```
def generate_adjacent_items(grid, k):
    """
    For a square grid, generates lists of all possible k numbers in every direction 
    (up, down, left, right and diagonally).
    """
    size = len(grid)
    for row in range(size):
        for col in range(size):
            # left -> right
            if row + k - 1 < size:
                yield [grid[row + index][col] for index in range(k)]

            # top -> bottom
            if col + k - 1 < size:
                yield [grid[row][col + index] for index in range(k)]

            # diagonal: top-left -> bottom-right
            if row + k - 1 < size and col + k - 1 < size:
                yield [grid[row + index][col + index] for index in range(k)]

            # diagonal: bottom - left -> top - right
            if row - k + 1 >= 0 and col + k - 1 < size:
                yield [grid[row - index][col + index] for index in range(k)]
```

<sub>(please recheck for off-by-ones)</sub>

Then, you can iterate over the generator and get your maximum number, e.g.:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

K = 4

# list_ints and generate_adjacent_items function definitions here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub_lists = generate_adjacent_items(list_ints(), K)

    max_sublist = max(sub_lists, key=lambda x: reduce(mul, x))
    print(max_sublist, reduce(mul, max_sublist))
```

Note that I'm using [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) and the [built-in `max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to determine the maximum of the multiplications, but you can do it "manually" the way you were doing it in your presented solution.

For the provided sample input, it prints:

```
[87, 97, 94, 89] 70600674
```

Comment: By "sample input" you mean the grid at the question link? Because the OP's code prints `70600674` (because `[89, 94, 97, 87]`) with that input, while yours prints `51267216`. OP's solution seems correct to me, am I missing something?

Comment: @ChatterOne stupid me, you are absolutely right, there was a bug. I've added a fix, thanks so much!

Comment: The generators part is what I needed.